# Module 'audioplayers' not found (when running on xcode only)

Tags: xcode, flutter, module, audio-player, flutter-ios

This might seem like a duplicate question but I've tried all the solutions without getting any result.

Here's the case:

The project runs fine on vscode.
The project archive also succeeds.
But when it comes to running using xcode I’m getting this error:

```
Module 'audioplayers' not found on xcode flutter.
```

Please help it's been a week now and I'm stuck.
ios version in podfile is set 12.0 as well as deployment target and deployment info.

If anyone had a similar issue please help.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: any luck?? we are facing the same issue here..

Comment: Sorry, no luck. 
However, it's probably something that has to do with xcode project settings because the app works fine on vscode and achieves successfully.

Comment: Hello @fabricio did you solve it? I ran the app from VSCode it worked fine but the problem is inside XCode settings.

Comment: Hi Mjad, we couldn't use it and we didn't have the time to wait for a solution, ended up using the library flutter sound.. and it worked.

Comment: I think that the problem is the same as https://github.com/bluefireteam/audioplayers/issues/308